# how could I find and extract a punctuation from a word of a paragraph text file?

Tags: c, string

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fO;

    fO = fopen("random.txt", "r");

    size_t size = 0;
    int len = 0;

    // initialize it for the getline() and strtok()
    char *line = NULL;

    // loop through the file
    node *head = NULL;

    while (getline(&line, &size, fO) != -1) {
        // strip newline
        line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = 0;

        char *word = strtok(line," ");
        char *mark;
    
        while (word != NULL){
            word = strtok(NULL," ");
             
            //why would this part make mark == 44?
            if(ispunct(word[strlen(word)-1]) != 0){
                int w = word[strlen(word)-1];
                itoa(w, mark, 10);
                printf("%s mark\n", mark);
                //i was hoping that it would be punctuation of type const *char
            }
        }
    }

    //free at end
    free(line);
```

the file is like(for eg):

```
lorem ipsum,
dolor.
sit amet con,
sec it.
```

the file has unpredictable numbers of words on each line.
I thought I was getting a character with `mark = word[strlen(word)-1]`. I expected to get a comma or period. Does anyone know why it ended up as an integer of 44?

Comment: I think the 44 is the ascii value of ",".  I just am not sure why word[num] would return that.

Comment: Yes, 44 is the ascii value of a comma. `itoa` takes an integer and converts it to a string. Since `w` is 44, the string is `"44"`. BTW, `char *mark` should be `char mark[100]`, unless your version of `itoa` allocates memory.

Comment: Do you want to remove punctuations from all words OR just list punctuations in the paragraph?

Comment: @sparkot I just wanted to separate the punctuation from the word.  (isolate it as another word) I just needed the punctuation to be `char *mark` so I could add the words and punctuation separately into a linked list.

Comment: Still unclear. What are you trying to achieve with this program?

Comment: @sparkot Sorry. I was just trying to add every word and piece of punctuation separately into a linked list. I was able to add every word (without punctuation) into a linked list, I just did not know exactly how to separate the words that did have punctuation.